# onClick of background of RemoteView unecpected behaviour

Tags: android, kotlin, android-widget, remoteview

I want my widget to show a list with a clickable button and clickable background on the ListItem that contains the button. I created a service, that distinguishes between the different events, but the click on the background is never registered, if the `onClickFillIntent` is set on the button. 
(I already tried setting multiple `onClickFillIntents` on other things, like a `TextView` and a button, this works flawlessly. Everything **but** the background works.)

TLDR;
why does `intent1` work, but `intent2` doesnt?
There is no error in logcat.

**widget.kt**

```
class Widget() : AppWidgetProvider() {

override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, Ids: IntArray) {
    for (i in Ids.indices) {
        val views = RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.classificationwidget)
        views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_list, context.intentFor<WidgetService>())
            views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_list, PendingIntent.getService(context,0,context.intentFor<DataCollectorService>("someAction"), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT))
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(Ids[i], views)
        }
    }
}

class WidgetService : RemoteViewsService() {
    override fun onGetViewFactory(intent: Intent): RemoteViewsFactory {
        return WidgetViews(this.applicationContext)
    }
}

class WidgetViews(private val context: Context) : RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

    override fun getViewAt(position: Int): RemoteViews? {
        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widgetlistitem)
        val intent1 = context.intentFor<MyService>(ACTION to "1")
        views.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_button, intent1)
        val intent2 = context.intentFor<MyService>(ACTION to "2")
        views.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_item_background, intent2) 
        return views
    }
    ... (rest of the methods)
}
```

**widgetlistitem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget_item_background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:background="@drawable/card"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/widget_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="Jetzt" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**widget_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/widget_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:listitem="@layout/widgetlistitem">
</ListView>
```